# CREATE TABLE returns error referring to sp_changeobjectowner and a non-existing schema

Tags: sql-server

A little challenge for the MS Sql Server experts out there...

I have a database on a SQL Server 2008 R2 server.
I have created a schema named MPP and a handful of table for this schema. 
The tables were originally created in the default dbo schema and then moved to the new schema using the sp_changeobjectowner procedure. The tables were however created and dropped a few times before I got it to work as I wanted.

To the problem... Whenever I now create a new table, regardless in the default dbo schema or I get one error message per table in the new schema referring to an error in the sp_changeobjectowner procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (d INT);

Msg 15001, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_changeobjectowner, Line 64
Object 'ASBJOR.TEST_TABELL' does not exist or is not a valid object for this operation.
```

There is a database user named ASBJOR, but no schema.
If I add a new table to the MPP schema the number of error messages will increase and one of the messages refers to the new table.

I've tried to create a new table in the default dbo schema and move it to the MPP schema using the ALTER SCHEMA MPP TRANSFER... command, but new table still appears in the error messages.

I've looked through the sys.objects, sys.tables, sys.schemas and sys.database_principals tables but I can't find anything wrong.

Any ideas what could cause this error message or where I can look for more hardcore details in the database?

Comment: Sounds like there's a DDL Trigger out there that's firing when you create a table. https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2231002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use [`sp_changeobjectowner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changeobjectowner-transact-sql) - it's been deprecated since 2005. Always use [`ALTER SCHEMA ... TRANSFER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql).

As for the error, check for a DDL trigger in that database:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE parent_class = 0;
```

Then check to see what those triggers are doing.

Comment: I've become aware of the deprecation of this procedure, but of course after using it...
I did find a DDL trigger on the database level which plays around with this procedure for some reason, so now I'm able to fix my problem.

Thanks a lot for your help Aaron! :)